# Get an array slice of 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I have got a 2d String array. How can I check a slice of it? For example row 3, up to 6th element there

I have tried

```
  String arr[][] = new String[3][6]
  arr[3][4] = "example"
  if (Arrays.asList(arr).subList(3,6).contains("example"))
            System.out.print("yes");
```

But this doesn't work. It works only for 1d array? Also, instead of using contains how can one check whether all elements are null in the slice array?

Comment: elaborate please, it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: well, I want to only get the slice of the 2d array arr[3][6] and check whether it contains "example" without looping through the whole array

Comment: you can just get the value stored at  `array[3][6]`, what you mean bu slicing further ?

Comment: @user3758223, It sounds like you are trying to get the entire row from `arr[3]`?

Comment: What do you consider a slice of a multidimensional array?

Comment: oh sorry, I mean from arr[3][0] up to arr[3][6] check all cells whether they contain the specific word without a loop

Comment: merlin2011 not the entire row but say the row up to a specific index but yes you are right in your thoughts

Comment: I'm not quite certain you completely understand what String[][] is in Java.  Think of your variable arr[][] as a checkerboard, 3 squares wide by 4 squares high.  Each one of those squares can hold (a reference to) a different String.  The statement `arr[3][4] = "example"` is storing the String "example" in that specific square.  It has no effect on the squares nearby.

Comment: user2321368 I do understand arrays. You probably don't understand what I mean. I want to check the whole row 3 from index 0 up to index 6 whether these cells in it contain the word "example"

Comment: @user3758223, See my answer below. Row 3 is actually index `2`, and you also need to specify the row before using sublist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, arrays are zero-indexed in Java, so if you declare an array with first dimension `3`, the maximum index is `2`.

Second, if you want to look at the slices of the third row, you should specify the index `2` explicitly before converting to a list.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ArrayGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String arr[][] = new String[3][6];
        arr[2][4] = "example";
        if (Arrays.asList(arr[2]).subList(3,6).contains("example"))
            System.out.println("yes");    
    }
}
```

Output:

```
yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in javadoc Arrays:

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(T[] original, int from, int to)
```

where

original is, for example, arr[3]

from is 0

to is 7

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T[],%20int,%20int%29](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: But that would copy the whole array and take up memory which is bad since I will have to do these checks in specific slices of the array many times.

Answer (score 0):

The curent way to do it is just :

```
if (Arrays.asList(arr[3]).contains("example"))
        System.out.print("yes");
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You declare that `String arr[][] = new String[3][6]`, it means simply 3 rows 6 columns structure.

Can assign value, in this case row,

- `arr[0][...] = <assigned-value>`   //row 1
- `arr[1][...] = <assigned-value>`   //row 2
- `arr[2][...] = <assigned-value>`   //row 3

But it will not work as you expected

- `arr[3][4] = "example"`  //row 4, here throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`